# How do i dispose the bitmap in form1 and what interval speed should the timer1 set to?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a new class I have this method:

```
public Bitmap CaptureWindowToMemory(IntPtr handle)
{
    Image img = CaptureWindow(handle);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img);
    bmp.Save("foo.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    return bmp;
}
```

If I will not dispose the bmp after some minutes I will get out of memory exception on the bmp instance line.

In form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        IntPtr windowHandle;
        ScreenCapture sc;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("GameCapture");

            foreach (Process p in processes)
            {
                windowHandle = p.MainWindowHandle;
            }

            this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            sc = new ScreenCapture();


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;

        }

        int countimages = 0;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.pictureBox1.Image = sc.CaptureWindowToMemory(windowHandle);
            countimages += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the CaptureWindow method from the new class:

```
public Image CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
        {
            // get te hDC of the target window
            IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);
            // get the size
            User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
            User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
            int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
            int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
            // create a device context we can copy to
            IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
            // create a bitmap we can copy it to,
            // using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
            IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);
            // select the bitmap object
            IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
            // bitblt over
            GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, GDI32.SRCCOPY);
            // restore selection
            GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
            // clean up 
            GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
            User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);
            // get a .NET image object for it
            Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
            // free up the Bitmap object
            GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            return img;
        }
```

If I will dispose the bitmap in the class then I will get exception invalid parameter on the line

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = sc.CaptureWindowToMemory(windowHandle);
```

So how should I handle it ?

Second problem is that the timer interval in the designer is set to 1ms.
And still when running the program I see the images in the pictureBox1 like a movie but it's still not smooth enough I think. In a real move the frame rate is 25 images(frames) per second ? How should I do it in my program with the timer ?

Comment: You can't get a windows timer to fire any faster than 15ms even if you set it to 1ms.

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? There are probably better ways to do it than this.

Comment: You should keep a reference to the `Bitmap` and when you create each new one - and after you assign it to the `PictureBox` - dispose the previous one.

Comment: Andy Lamb I have external process that show a video inside a window in the process. What i'm trying to do first is to get a screenshot every X seconds/ms of the process whole window and show the images from the memory in the pictureBox1 so it will looks like a video in the pictureBox.

Comment: I'm not trying to get the external process video window but the whole window of the process and display it in pictureBox1 so I see in the pictureBox1 like the external process it is. And it's working beside the two problems I mentioned in my question.

Comment: You are making a copy of the image and do not call Dispose() at all.  Sure, that is not going to last very long.  Just cast the return value to (Bitmap) so you don't have to copy.  And add if (pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose(); before you assign it.

Comment: Hans I added the null check and the disposing of the picturebox1 image. But what do you mean by cast the return value to Bitmap ? You mean in form1 to cast to bitmap some variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to change your code to correctly disposed used bitmaps is to change your `timer1_Tick` method as follows:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sc.CaptureWindowToMemory(windowHandle, (bitmap) =>
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;

        countimages += 1;
    });
}
```

And `ScreenCapture` class this way:

```
private Bitmap currentBitmap;
public void CaptureWindowToMemory(IntPtr handle, Action<Bitmap> action)
{
    using (var img = CaptureWindow(handle))
    {
        var newBitmap = new Bitmap(img);
        newBitmap.Save("foo.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        action(newBitmap);

        if (currentBitmap != null)
            currentBitmap.Dispose();

        currentBitmap = newBitmap;
    }
}
```

Or you can try to serve your picture through a intermediate place (don't know if disk is the best option). Such approach takes around two or three times memory compared to first one with saving to HDD.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var path = sc.CaptureWindowToMemory(windowHandle);
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = path;

    countimages += 1;
}

public string CaptureWindowToMemory(IntPtr handle)
{
    var name = "foo.png";
    using (var img = CaptureWindow(handle))
    using (var currentBitmap = new Bitmap(img))
        currentBitmap.Save(name, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

    return name;
}
```

**Update:** Code snippets are updated thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734895/how-do-i-dispose-the-bitmap-in-form1-and-what-interval-speed-should-the-timer1-s/36745268#comment61071834_36745268).

Comment: Don't dispose the old bitmap while it is still used within the picturebox. The second approach is better, but much slower due to the repeated encoding, saving and loading of the bitmap.

Comment: Thanks, changed snippets a bit to workaround this issue with disposing

Comment: That first approach is much much better now, but I don't understand why you save the bitmap under that approach?

Comment: It was saved in original code, I just left that line. For displaying image it is not needed, of course.

Answer (score -1):

> If I will not dispose the bmp after some minutes I will get out of
>   memory exception on the bmp instance line.

I tried to recreate your situation but I can't repeat it.

You didn't give CaptureWindow(handle), so I use this function in your project.

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct Rect
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect);

    public static Bitmap CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
    {

        var rect = new Rect();
        GetWindowRect(handle, ref rect);
        var bounds = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top);

        if (bounds.Width == 0 && bounds.Height == 0)
        {
            bounds.Width = 1;
            bounds.Height = 1;
        }

        var result = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

        if(bounds.Width != 1 )
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
            {
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            }

        return result;
    }
```

Way to dispose Bitmap before update PictureBox, you can use this in your timer

```
        var bmp = sc.CaptureWindowToMemory(windowHandle);
        //Backup old image in pictureBox
        var oldImage = pictureBox1.Image;
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        //Release resources from old image
        if (oldImage != null)
            ((IDisposable)oldImage).Dispose();
```

> what interval speed should the timer1 set to?

I think you don't need to use timer for update paint. More optimal will use the main loop in a separate thread. For example

```
    int countimages = 0;
    Task tasks;
    bool StartUpdateTask = false;
    private  void UpdateTask()
    {
        if (StartUpdateTask)
        {
            tasks = Task.Run(() =>
            {
               // Action to update paint. 
                 ...
                if(countimages%10 == 0){
                  // Action to save paint
                  ...
                } 
                System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref countimages);
                UpdateTask();
            });
        }
    } 


 private void button_RunTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        if (!StartUpdateTask &&( tasks == null || tasks.IsCompleted)) { 
           StartUpdateTask = true;
           UpdateTask();                
        }else
           StartUpdateTask = false;

        button_RunTest.BackColor = (StartUpdateTask) ? Color.Green : this.BackColor;              
    }
```

Comment: You right my mistake. I added the CaptureWindow method to my question I forgot about it sorry.

Comment: You can use my function if you want and check.

Comment: This isn't an answer. It should be deleted.